# How to implement the sql in postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

my arm is to implement the sql like:

step1:
set variable dev:

```
\set dev '(select COALESCE(STDDEV_POP(answer_count+created_at/600000), 0) from question_view where created_at > {$limitTime})'
```

step2:
get hotest question list:

```
SELECT id, floor(q.answer_count+add_time/600000-@dev) as sort from question_view WHERE state in (1, -1) and add_time > {$limitTime} order by sort
```

How can I do in php?

```
$sql = "
        \set dev '(select COALESCE(STDDEV_POP(answer_count+created_at/600000), 0) from question_view where created_at > {$limitTime})'
        ";
        $pdo->exec($sql);

        $sql = "
        SELECT id, floor(q.answer_count+add_time/600000-@dev) as sort from question_view WHERE state in (1, -1) and add_time > {$limitTime}
        ";

        if ($max) {
            $sql .= " and sort < {$max} ";
        }

        $sql .= " ORDER BY id DESC
            OFFSET {$offset}
            LIMIT {$limit}";

        $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm = $stm->execute();
```

But the code doesn't work~~

Comment: `\set dev` isn't sql. It's a command to a particular PostgreSQL client program, [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html). It sets a psql variable. You're not using the psql client. You're using PHP with PDO.